# Separate with different characters sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, delimiter

So I have a column which contains multiple different strings. If the string contains a _ it has to be split on that character. For the others I use would use a separate rule like: If it starts with 4FH, GWO, CTW and doesn't have an _ then it has to split after 3 characters. If it starts with 4 and doesn't have an _.. etc..

```
Example

|Source    | 
|EC_HKT    |
|4FHHTK    |
|ABC_GJE   |
|4SHARED   |
|ETK_ETK-40|

etc..
```

What i want as a result is

```
|Source|Instance|
|EC    |HKT     |
|4FH   |HTK     |
|ABC   |GJE     |
|4     |SHARED  |
|ETK   |40      |
```

As a start I first tried

```
SELECT
    LEFT(lr.Source, CHARINDEX('_',lr.Source)) AS Source,
    RIGHT(lr.Source, LEN(lr.Source) - CHARINDEX('_', lr.Source)) AS Interface,
```

But this would only work if all the results had a _ . Any tips or ideas? Would a CASE WHEN THEN work?

Comment: Please explain your rules for splitting the string.  It is not obvious.

Comment: I added it in there.

Comment: These are arbitrary texts and rules, you'll pretty much need a mapping to do this, hence pretty much doing the split manually. You can start to build said mapping by using simple rules, but at the end, this won't end up in a simple transformation. (e.g. is 10SHARED mapped to 10 and SHARED or 1 and 0SHARED? Is ABC_ABC-GJE mapped to ABC and GJE or ABC and ABC-GJE? Why?

Comment: This is too arbitrary to apply any common logic to. I would create a function that implements your rules and calculates the character position to split on, you can then use this to split the string in half.

Comment: If it starts with 4FH it also starts with 4 so how do you know to split after 4 or after 4FH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires a little creativity and no doubt more work than what I've done here, however this gives you at least one pattern to work with and enhance as required.

The following uses a simple function to apply basic rules from your sample data to derive the point to split your string, plus some additional removal of characters and removal of the source part if it also exists in the instance part.

If more than one "rule" matches, it uses the one with higher number of matching characters.

Function:

```
create or alter function splitpos(@string varchar(50))
returns table as
return
(
    with map as (
        select * from (values ('4FH'),('GWO'),('CTW'),('4'))m(v)
    )
    select IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex('_',@string),0)-1,Max(Len(m.v))) pos
    from map m
    where @string like m.v + '%'
)
```

Query:

```
select l.v source, Replace(Replace(Replace(Stuff(source,1,pos,''),'_',''),'-',''),l.v,'') instance
from t
cross apply dbo.splitpos(t.source)
cross apply (values(Left(source,pos)))l(v)
```

[Demo DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=be2bdf0325e8ca994c7fa7d5ebe28d3c)

Answer (score 0):

To split with different rules, use a `CASE` *expression*. ([W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp))

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN lr.Source LIKE '4FH%' AND CHARINDEX('_', lr.Source) = 0 
    THEN LEFT(lr.Source, 3)
    ...
 END as Source
```

If theses are separate columns then you would need a case statement for each column.

Comment: @jarlh thanks, I changed it to match Microsoft and not be so f**lish

Comment: A case _statement_ is a stored procedure construction for conditional execution of code. A case _expression_ returns a value, and can be used pretty much anywhere you want a value. All according to the ANSI/ISO SQL standard.